# Vertx, Connexion to data base blocking by JDBC Client

Tags: java, vert.x

i'm using vertx 3.4.1, i have a problem with JDBC Connection when the username or password of the data base is wrong, vertx try to reconnect every many time and that cause blocking the user compte by the data base.

this is my personnal methode that geving me the database client:

```
public void getConnection(Handler<AsyncResult<SQLConnection>> resultHandler){
        if(this.client == null){
            logger.error(Error.BD_CLIENT_NOT_FOUND);
            resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(Error.BD_CLIENT_NOT_FOUND.toString()));
        }else {

            this.client.getConnection(connection -> {
                if (connection.succeeded()) {
                    resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(connection.result()));
                } else {
                    logger.error(connection.cause().getMessage());
                    resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(Error.ER_DB_CONX.toString()));
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

can you help me please? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try `client.close();`

Comment: Please post your code.